# Little Snitch shows ping flood to 0.0.0.192

Tags: network, firewall, ping, wireshark

My Little Snitch Network Monitor tells me my machine is ping'ing 0.0.0.192 every second.  What's going on?

EDIT:

A Wireshark capture tells me this ping has

Source 0.0.76.188

Destination 0.0.0.192

[image: Wireshark Capture]

Comment: ..what process ?

Comment: It just shows 'ping'  I'd expect it to show 'ping via xxxxx' but it just shows 'ping'

Comment: Did you modify ip tables or did some other reroute configuration? The obvious cause would be a modification or piece of software that someone installed.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.  A `netstat -nr` doesn't show any non-standard things

Comment: Looks like a maroding wildcard mask...

Comment: After another 1+ million pings I still haven't found why.

Comment: Can you show us the detail of a full packet?

Comment: @OrtomalaLokni a couple macbooks and OSX releases later, the problem has since been vanished.  Will definitely get back to this thread when/if it comes back.